# Embed SQL Server Express silent installation in setup project in VS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, batch-file, setup-project

I had a problem embedding SQL Server Express silent installation in a setup project using VS 2019.

My incorrect solution to the problem is as the following:

1. created a batch file: (Note : This is all one physical line. It's been broken over many lines for display purposes only)

   ```
   start SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe /qs /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=XXXXXX /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS" /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /SAPWD="MYSECRETPASSWORD" /SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT="True" /FILESTREAMLEVEL=1 /TCPENABLED=1 /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /SECURITYMODE=SQL
   ```
2. I made a custom action in the setup project that have the arguments:

   ```
   /c "[TARGETDIR]subdirectoryname\batchfile.bat"
   ```
3. The problem is that it only extracts the SQL Server but is not installing it writing in the cmd

   > not enough memory resources are available to process this command.

Is there is fix to this problem? If not: how can I embed a silent install to SQL Server Express in my setup file?

Comment: In the batch, try `start "Window Title" SQLE...`. The Window Title can be anything you like, even an empty string. If it is omitted, the first quoted string in the command parameters may be being taken as a window title, which may interfere with the parameter-string delivered to  `SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe`.

Comment: when i run the bat alone, it runs fine but when i run it from the cmd in the installation process i does not work well